# Aggregate all documents with the newest date in one query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following documents in a mongo collection and want to select all documents which has the latest `LastUpdate` value.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1234a1acb3fbf26334ef6117"), "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2021-01-10T00:00:00Z"), "ProductName" : "Foo" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1234a1b9b3fbf26334ef6118"), "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2021-02-05T00:00:00Z"), "ProductName" : "Bar" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("1234a1c8b3fbf26334ef6119"), "LastUpdate" : ISODate("2021-02-05T00:00:00Z"), "ProductName" : "Foo-Bar" }
```

My first guess was, to sort `LastUpdate` with `-1` and then group like:

```
{
  _id: "$ProductName",
  LastUpdate: { $first: "$LastUpdate" },
  documents: { $push : "$$ROOT" }
}
```

But in `documents` there are always all documents (in this sample 3) instead of the only two with the date `2021-02-05`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$LastUpdate", items: {$push: "$$ROOT"} }},
    {$sort: {LastUpdate: -1}},
    {$limit: 1},
    {$project: {"items": 1}}
])
```

Here I group by the `LastUpdate` field (and for each group push the relevant documents into `items`), then sort and select the group with the latest `LastUpdate` value.